# Given a stream of number, like 1,3,5,4,6,9, I was asked to print them like 1,3-6,9

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, heap

Given a stream of number, like 1,3,5,4,6,9, I was asked to print them like 1,3-6,9. My approach was to hold min 2 numbers in a maxHeap and max 2 numbers in a minHeap. And I have come up with a following solution. Do you have any suggestion to make it more optimized? Its time complexity is O(nlogn).

```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> mergingMiddleNums (int[] arr){

    if (arr == null || arr.length < 3){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }

     ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
     Queue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(); 

     Queue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
         @Override
            public int compare(Integer num1, Integer num2) {
                return num2-num1;
            }
        });

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
        minHeap.add(arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
        maxHeap.add(arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 2 ; i <arr.length; i++){

        if(arr[i] > minHeap.peek()){
             minHeap.poll();
             minHeap.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }       
     result.add(minHeap.poll());
     result.add(minHeap.poll());


     for (int i = 2 ; i <arr.length; i++){

         if(arr[i] < maxHeap.peek()){
             maxHeap.poll();
             maxHeap.add(arr[i]);             

        }
    }

    result.add(maxHeap.poll());
    result.add(maxHeap.poll());

    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;

   }
```

Comment: If you intend to sort anyway, I'd start by sorting and then examing adjacent numbers.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to solve it without sorting in this approach?

Comment: I think that i might create a new stack and queue , and then combine them but not sure how optimized it is

Comment: What if the array contains 1, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6? What should be displayed?

Comment: I think you can use the bubble sort to sort Consecutive numbers out. and use another array to store all these numbers using quick sort.

Comment: As my understanding, it should display  1,3,6,9

Comment: @Kun buble sort makes the case worse with quadratic time complexity

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether your output needs to stream or not. Let's start with non-streaming output, because your current implementation addresses this.

Your code's overall complexity will be, at best, O(nLog(n)), but you can radically simplify your implementation by storing every incoming number in a collection, converting it to an array, and sorting it, before scanning over the items sequentially to identify continuous ranges. The most expensive operation here would be the sort, which would define your runtime. To save space, you could use a set or heap collection to avoid storing duplicates (the formation of which will be somewhere near O(nLog(n)) - which being the same runtime, remains collapsed at a total runtime of O(nLog(n))

If your code is expected to stream the printing along with output, that is, to print ranges as they are formed and move to the next range whenever the next number encountered is not directly adjacent to the current range, you can do it in O(n) by storing the numeric bounds of the current range as you go and either printing and resetting them if the currently-examined number is not adjacent or inside the bounds, or by expanding the bounds if it is.

Comment: What if I go with a binary search to find max and min in the beginning array and then conduct two more binary search after eliminating first max and min, end the end i can put all the number in a max heap and print it

Comment: You could definitely do that, but I would argue that you're adding unnecessary complexity. If you're going to sort, sort first and then identify the ranges (making the non-sort complexity essentially a linear scan).

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation would be to use a hashtable to store wether each integer was present in the input values or not. Then, it's simply a matter of iterating from the min value to the max and use the hashtable to find out where are the number clusters.

Such implementation would basically be O(n) with n=max-min (and not number of items in list). So if you have many numbers within a reasonably small range of values, then you could be better than a sort-based approach.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Test {
private int min=0, max=-1;
private Map<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] input={1,3,5,4,6,9};
    Test t = new Test();
    t.readNumbers(input);
    t.outputRanges();
}


public void readNumbers(int[] values) {
    // Get min and max values, and store all existing values in map
    for(int v:values) {
        if(first || v<min) min=v;
        if(first || v>max) max=v;
        first=false;
        map.put(v, 1);
     }
}

public void outputRanges() {
    // Iterate from min to max and use map to find out existing
    // values
    int last=min-2;
    boolean inRange=false;
    first=true;

    for(int i=min;i<=max;++i) {
        if(map.get(i)==null) continue;

        if(i==last+1) {
            inRange=true;
        } else {
            if(inRange) {
                closeRange(last);
                inRange=false;
            }
            output(i);
        }

        last=i;
    }

    if(inRange) closeRange(last);
}

private boolean first;
private void commaUnlessFirst() {
    if(!first) System.out.printf(",");
    first=false;
}
private void output(int i) {
    commaUnlessFirst();
    System.out.printf("%d", i);
}
private void closeRange(int i) {
    System.out.printf("-%d", i);
}
}
```